# Using ngClass 'Missing expected }' error being received

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to conditionally add a class to a list item (through a child components selector), depending on the images width size. The width size is hard coded when the new image item is created in another component.

I keep receiving the error message :

> 'Missing expected }' in my gallery-list.component.html file.

I can't see that I am missing } anywhere. Can anyone help?

Here is the gallery-list html code:

```
  <ul class="container">
    <li class="item-list-container" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 160 }'><app-image-item
    class="image-item"
    *ngFor="let imageEl of images;"
    [image]="imageEl"
    [ngClass] ="{ 
    'widthOne': imageEl.widthSize === 50px, 
    'widthTwo': imageEl.widthSize === 100px,
    'widthThree': imageEl.widthSize === 150px,
    'widthFour': imageEl.widthSize === 200px,
    }"
    (click)="onImageSelect(imageEl.id)"   
    ></app-image-item>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can't compare as `imageEl.widthSize === 50px` it has to be `imageEl.widthSize === '50px'`

Comment: @JohnDev, You need to consider using ternary operator.. 
 Working Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-kxtgt1

Answer (score 1):

That's not a correct syntax. Take a look at [this similar demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngclass-tczgmr?file=app/app.component.html). Try

```
  <ul class="container">
    <li class="item-list-container" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 160 }'><app-image-item
    class="image-item"
    *ngFor="let imageEl of images;"
    [image]="imageEl"
    [ngClass] ="getClass(imageEl.widthSize)"
    (click)="onImageSelect(imageEl.id)"   
    ></app-image-item>
    </li>
</ul>
```

in **ts** file:

```
getClass(widthSize): string{
  if(widthSize === "50px") {
    return "widthOne"
  }
  if(widthSize === "100px") {
    return "widthTwo"
  }
  if(widthSize === "150px") {
    return "widthThree"
  }
  if(widthSize === "200px") {
    return "widthFour"
  }
}
```

Note:

I would recommend you to add a property on `images` array deciding the class which has to be added, rather than using function call as I did using `getClass()`.  Using function on `HTML` is a bad practice.

If the image is coming from some service, you can use `.map` and add `className` property on it.

Comment: @JohnDev:  PLease mark it as an answer so that it can help others looking for similar problem